# anyone can explain the "field of view"

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

In graphics software, sometimes we saw "field of view" for camera. Can someone explain what does it mean?

Answer (score 9):

The field of view (in the gluPerspective call) is the angle in degrees between a plane which passes through the camera position and the top of your screen and another plane which passes through the camera position and the bottom of your screen.

Edit:
Since you need not have a full-screen viewport: Any line which is projected to (x1, 0)-(x2, 0) lies in the first plane, any line that is projected to (x3, height)-(x4, height) lies in the second, where height is the height of your viewport in pixels.

Comment: It's unintuitive, but true, that FOV is vertical and not horizontal.

Answer (score 5):

The field of view is normally the horizontal field of view.

This is the angular extent of the observable world [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view)

The larger the field of view the more of the scene you can see, but each bit will be seen at a lower resolution.

The vertical field of view is related to the horizontal by the aspect ratio of the view. A square view will have the same horizontal and vertical FoV. A landscape view will have a smaller vertical FoV while a portrait view will have a larger vertical FoV.